# Rename LAS point cloud classification

Tags: classification, las, point-cloud

I'm looking for a way to change a las classification name. Want to change class 64 unknown to class 64 Culvert.

How do I change the name of the las class? Is it best to do it within the LS header?

Comment: The class names can be set in extended variable length records for ASPRS version 1.4 release 14+ *provided your PDRF is 6-10* https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/LAS_1_4_r14.pdf#page=44. If you are using class 0-5 there isn't enough space in the classification byte as 3 bits are used for flags, leaving only enough bits to store 0-31. What programming language are you intending to modify your LAS files?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your response. I could use python or Linux using the C programming language.

Comment: The structures as written are C style so shouldn't be too hard to understand, a good muse might be https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/master/LASlib/src/lasreader_las.cpp. The extended variable length records differ from the standard variable length records in that the standard records appear after the header and before the first point record, the extended records are at the end of the file, that's good news: open the file as write/binary,  update the header to point to the EVLR then seek to the end and add your structures: EVLR header + class lookup (be sure to structure pack to byte).

Comment: Thank you, Michal. Is there a way to possible do this process within python?

Comment: Yes, you might need to use pickle https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html and struct https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html to convert your variables into bytes but writing to binary files is possible, all you need to do is seek to the correct file offsets and write, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367007/python-how-to-write-to-a-binary-file. **You must be absolutely precise about the offset and number of bytes**; you must also fill any unused bytes with 0 or a 3rd party reader might fail to read correctly.